# Android Studio Failed To Delete File

Tags: android, android-studio

When I try to run application in android studio, 
I face this error :

```
"Failed to delete: D:\WorkSpace\Fiducial\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values"
```

When clearing the project it works, but this is a time consuming operation.

Your help is appreciated

Comment: May be your root directory has read only permission.

Comment: Go to root folder for the app and delete `build` folder. See if this helps.

Comment: can u close open the project folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run Android Studio as Administrator.

If its doenst work Try File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart

Answer (score 0):

Go to File and select Invalidate Caches and Restart. Sometimes Android Studio behave abnormal. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am check it Are u open the project folder

`D:\WorkSpace\Fiducial\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values`

close it or back from one step values folder. After run your application should build success.